# In ENV i had written port, but in console it is returning undefined. Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, port

I have this error guys in console, if you can help me. Actually I had written that env port, but in console. it returns undefined.

```
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT
const { emailMessage } = require('./messageMail/sendMessage')
require('./db/db')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/contact', async (req, res) => {
try {
console.log(req.body)
await emailMessage(req.body)
res.send('namaky texe hasel')
} catch (err) {
console.log(err)
res.status(500).send(err)
}

})
app.listen(port , ()=>{
console.log(port)
})
```

Comment: Where did you write port? Are you using any libraries like `dotenv` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const express = require('express')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3333;
const { emailMessage } = require('./messageMail/sendMessage')
require('./db/db')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/contact', async (req, res) => {
try {
console.log(req.body)
await emailMessage(req.body)
res.send('namaky texe hasel')
} catch (err) {
console.log(err)
res.status(500).send(err)
}

})
app.listen(port , ()=>{
console.log(port)
})
```

This will work on your localhost on port 3333.

When you deploy your code in the server (like Heroku for example) `process.env.PORT` will set for the right server port.

If you want to use the .env in your project, try to use `npm install dotenv` and, finally, before `const port = process.env.PORT` you use `require('dotenv').config()`